# How to prevent foreach loop to display specific div if if matches?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I currently have this code:

```
foreach ($title_dump as $i => $title) {
  $prev_i = $i === 0 ? $i : $i - 1;
  if ($i > 0 and $title_dump[$prev_i] === $event->title) {
    echo '<div class="hide-this-element"></div>';
  } elseif ($i > 0 and $title_dump[$prev_i] != $event->title) {
  if ($i === $title_dump[$i]) {
    $show_event = '<div class="uk-text-left debugging">Stufe ' . $filtered_numbers . '</div>';
    echo $show_event;
  }
} elseif ($i === 0) {
  echo '<div class="uk-text-left debugging">Stufe ' . $filtered_numbers . '</div>';
  }
}
```

inside this I try to figure out how to prevent that `$show_event` is shown if the first `if` statement matches. With this I mean if `if ($i > 0 and $title_dump[$prev_i] === $event->title) {` matches I need to hide everything inside `if ($i === $title_dump[$i]) {` Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You want to hide everything or just one div?

Comment: @davidev just the div.

Answer (score 0):

If you loop your `$title_dump` and notice that there is a element, you do not want to print, you can use `continue;` statement to go to the next item in the foreach.

```
foreach ($title_dump as $i => $title) {
  $prev_i = $i === 0 ? $i : $i - 1;
  if ($i > 0 and $title_dump[$prev_i] === $event->title) {
    //Do not print anything
    //will exit the loop for this item, and go the next item
    continue;

  } elseif ($i > 0 and $title_dump[$prev_i] != $event->title) {
  if ($i === $title_dump[$i]) {
    $show_event = '<div class="uk-text-left debugging">Stufe ' . $filtered_numbers . '</div>';
    echo $show_event;
  }
} elseif ($i === 0) {
  echo '<div class="uk-text-left debugging">Stufe ' . $filtered_numbers . '</div>';
  }
}
```